# How do I deploy QT app (without static linking) that uses ODBC plugin?

Tags: qt, plugins, deployment, odbc

My application uses Qt SQL this way

```
QString servername = "SQL09.FreeMySQL.net";
QString dbname = "psiprobation";
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setConnectOptions();
QString dsn = QString("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;USER=jnchappell21;PASSWORD=XXXXXXX").arg(servername).arg(dbname);
db.setDatabaseName(dsn);
```

I have also included this in my code...

```
a.addLibraryPath(a.applicationDirPath()+"/plugins");
```

The "plugins" folder contains another folder "sqldrivers".  Inside "sqldrivers" is myodbc5.dll, myobdc5S.dll, qsqlodbc4.dll, and qsqlodbcd4.dll. (NOTE: the "plugins" folder is in the same directory as the executable)

Now that deployment stage has come, the application works perfectly on the system where Qt is installed; however, on other systems (where QT is not installed) I am unable to connect to the database even though the application will run (i.e. the GUI opens up and displays an error message).

The error message is: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified QODBC3: Unable to connect"

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: What is the exact error that is displayed?

Comment: The "error message" is not descriptive.  It is just a dialog that displays "Unknown Error Occurred".  This dialog is triggered only if(!db.open()).

Comment: The "Unknown Error Occurred" dialog is something I produced to show if an error occurred while accessing (or attempting to initially access) the database.

Comment: Oh :) I was trying to figure out a scenario where a dialog would actually be open to indicate an error condition but it is your own dialog then?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I am adding a QMessageBox right now to determine the exact error message.

Comment: I added the official error message to the question post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging plugin issues in Qt can be a pain. I never had much success trying to force a plugin location using `addLibraryPath()`. Before I ever figured out why, I discovered that Qt applications will look in the application root for the "leaf" directory of the plugin type involved. In your case, just put the `sqldrivers` directory in the root of your application (without nesting it inside a `plugins` directory).

One way to try to determine if you are in fact having a plugin location problem, try moving the driver files out of their location on your development machine (or rename them) and see if you get the same error.

Although directed at widget plugins, this page has some [plugin trouble shooting](http://www.dtic.upf.edu/~dgarcia/Codders/qtpluginnotloading.html) tips.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. I tried your suggestion of renaming/relocating some of the driver files. Unfortunately, I have been unsuccessful reproducing the error on the development machine.  I have also gone through several of the items listed in the link, but no luck yet.

Comment: I solved the problem.  I reinstalled the ODBC driver on the target machine, and it seems to have fixed the issue. However, I have no idea why it was causing the problem. Thank you for your time and efforts!